# what happens when calling ```touch .``` in linux?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

this is a very specific question

I'm mainly interested in the open() system calls the happen when running `touch .`.
So I ran `strace touch .` and saw that opennat() is called three times.

but I'm not really understanding whats going on; as `touch .` does not print anything in the console and does not create a new file named "." since "." is a pointer to the current folder and can be seen by running `ls -a` so nothing is created since that name is already in use.

this is my assumption:
open() is called to check if the specified file name already exits, if a file descriptor is returned this means that the name is already in use and the operation is canceled.

please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Probably you have to specify the exact version of `touch` (and the vendor). I have GNU coreutils 8.32, and its `touch` behaves as expected: calls a single `openat(2)` to create the potentially non-existent file and a single `utimensat(2)` to change the access time.

Comment: And I believe it's easier to find and read the source than to guess. `touch` is a pretty simple thing.

Comment: my version is also GNU coreutils 8.32 running on redhat.
I did actually read the documentation [link] (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) but I did not find find much about the system calls.
Simply googling it returned basic beginner touch tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `touch` prefers to use a file descriptor when touching files, since it's possible to write `touch - > foo` and expect the file `foo` to be touched.  As a result, it always tries to open the specified path as a writable file, and if that's possible, it then uses that file descriptor to update the file timestamp.

In this case, it's not possible to open `.` for writing, so `openat` returns `EISDIR`.  `touch` notices that it's a directory, so its call to its internal `fdutimensat` function gets an invalid file descriptor and falls back to using `utimensat` instead of `futimens`.

It isn't the case that the `openat` call is used to check that the file exists, but instead that using a file descriptor for many operations means that you don't have to deal with path resolution multiple times or handle symlinks, since all of those are resolved when the file descriptor is opened.  This is why many long-lived programs choose to open a file descriptor to their current working directory, then change directories, and then use the file descriptor with `fchdir` to change back.  Any pchanges to permissions after the program starts are not a problem.

Comment: You have answered my question thank you. My understanding was that directories also had file descriptors similar to files and that's why open() was used. Thank you again for explaining it.